# What is the relationship between UIView's setNeedsLayout, layoutIfNeeded and layoutSubviews?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

Can anyone give a definitive explanation on the relationship between `UIView's` `setNeedsLayout`, `layoutIfNeeded` and `layoutSubviews` methods? And an example implementation where all three would be used. Thanks.

What gets me confused is that if I send my custom view a `setNeedsLayout` message the very next thing it invokes after this method is `layoutSubviews`, skipping right over `layoutIfNeeded`. From the docs I would expect the flow to be `setNeedsLayout` > causes `layoutIfNeeded` to be called > causes `layoutSubviews` to be called.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I'm still trying to figure this out myself, so take this with some skepticism and forgive me if it contains errors.

`setNeedsLayout` is an easy one: it just sets a flag somewhere in the UIView that marks it as needing layout.  That will force `layoutSubviews` to be called on the view before the next redraw happens.  Note that in many cases you don't need to call this explicitly, because of the `autoresizesSubviews` property.  If that's set (which it is by default) then any change to a view's frame will cause the view to lay out its subviews.

`layoutSubviews` is the method in which you do all the interesting stuff.  It's the equivalent of `drawRect` for layout, if you will.  A trivial example might be:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    // Child's frame is always equal to our bounds inset by 8px
    self.subview1.frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 8.0, 8.0);
    // It seems likely that this is incorrect:
    // [self.subview1 layoutSubviews];
    // ... and this is correct:
    [self.subview1 setNeedsLayout];
    // but I don't claim to know definitively.
}
```

AFAIK `layoutIfNeeded` isn't generally meant to be overridden in your subclass.  It's a method that you're meant to call when you want a view to be laid out *right now*.  Apple's implementation might look something like this:

```
-(void)layoutIfNeeded {
    if (self._needsLayout) {
        UIView *sv = self.superview;
        if (sv._needsLayout) {
            [sv layoutIfNeeded];
        } else {
            [self layoutSubviews];
        }
    }
}
```

You would call `layoutIfNeeded` on a view to force it (and its superviews as necessary) to be laid out immediately.

Comment: Thank you - glad someone finally answered this. In the meantime I've also had to delve into setNeedsDisplay - which causes drawRect to be called - and contentMode. Only contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw will cause setNeedsDisplay to be called when a view's bounds changes. The other contentMode choices only cause the view to be scaled, shifted by some amount, or aligned to an edge. My custom UITableViewCell didn't want to redraw on orientation changes, it would only scale, until I set contentMode to UIViewContentModeRedraw.

Comment: I think perhaps the [self.subview1 layoutSubviews] in your code should be replaced with [self.subview1 setNeedsLayout]. Since layoutSubviews is meant to be overridden but is not meant to be called from or to another view. Either the framework determines when to call it (by grouping together multiple layout requests into one call for efficiency) or you indirectly do by calling layoutIfNeeded somewhere in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Correction to my above comment: "...Since layoutSubviews is meant to be overridden or called from self but is not meant to be called from or to another view..."

Comment: I'm really not sure about `[subview1 layoutSubviews]`.  It could very well be that, like `drawRect`, you're not supposed to call it directly.  But I'm not sure if calling `setNeedsLayout` during the layout phase will cause the view to be laid out during the same layout phase or if it's delayed until the next one.

It would be nice to see an answer from somebody who *really* understands how this all works...

Answer (score 35):

I would like to add on n8gray's answer that in some cases you will need to call `setNeedsLayout` followed by `layoutIfNeeded`.

Let's say for example that you wrote a custom view extending UIView, in which the positioning of subviews is complex and cannot be done with autoresizingMask or iOS6 AutoLayout. The custom positioning can be done by overriding `layoutSubviews`.

As an example, let's say that you have a custom view that has a `contentView` property and an `edgeInsets` property that allows to set the margins around the contentView. `layoutSubviews` would look like this:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(
        self.bounds.origin.x + self.edgeInsets.left,
        self.bounds.origin.y + self.edgeInsets.top,
        self.bounds.size.width - self.edgeInsets.left - self.edgeInsets.right,
        self.bounds.size.height - self.edgeInsets.top - self.edgeInsets.bottom); 
}
```

If you want to be able to animate the frame change whenever you change the `edgeInsets` property, you need to override the `edgeInsets` setter as follows and call `setNeedsLayout` followed by `layoutIfNeeded`:

```
- (void) setEdgeInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)edgeInsets {
    _edgeInsets = edgeInsets;
    [self setNeedsLayout]; //Indicates that the view needs to be laid out 
                           //at next update or at next call of layoutIfNeeded, 
                           //whichever comes first 
    [self layoutIfNeeded]; //Calls layoutSubviews if flag is set
}
```

That way, if you do the following, if you change the edgeInsets property inside an animation block, the frame change of the contentView will be animated.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
    customView.edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(45, 17, 18, 34);
}];
```

If you do not add the call to layoutIfNeeded in the setEdgeInsets method, the animation won't work because the layoutSubviews will get called at the next update cycle, which equates to calling it outside of the animation block.

If you only call layoutIfNeeded in the setEdgeInsets method, nothing will happen as the setNeedsLayout flag is not set.

Comment: Or you should just be able to call `[self layoutIfNeeded]` within the animation block after setting the edge insets.