# Changing position and size of UILabel in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to change the position and size of a `UILabel` inside my custom `UITableViewCell` depending on a certain condition being true. In my custom `UITableViewCell` header file, I have a `UILabel` declared as such:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *stepText;
```

I want to change the location an size of the `UILabel` based on a condition. In the view that holds my `UITableView` I perform the check as such:

```
if(step.picture == nil){
    CGRect frame = cell.stepText.frame;
    frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    cell.stepText.frame = frame;
}
```

I have used an NSLog inside that check and I have verified that it gets executed when ever the condition is true, however, the location and size of my label in my custom cell does not change.

What are my doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are you performing the check?

Comment: I am performing the check in the view that holds the tableview that uses my custom tableviewcell, in a -configurecell method that gets called for every cell on my tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try `-setNeedsLayout` after you change anything. Doing that with a simplified version of your code above yields:

```
if (step.picture == nil) {
    cell.stepText.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Better yet, you could put your re/sizing code in `-layoutSubviews`, and call `[cell setNeedsLayout]` when anything changes. On the relationship of these two methods, confer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2931712), or many other sources.

Comment: Hey thanks, but I haven't defined a setNeedsLayout method, is that a method I have to define or can I include a header that will allow me to use this method?

Comment: Never mind, I get what your saying, lemme try and I will update everyone. Thanks again!

Comment: It's a built-in method of `UIView`, so it might be more like `[cell setNeedsLayout]`. I've corrected above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add custom UILabel to cell.contentView.
If you want custom label use:
- in file .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *ttitle;
```

-in  file .m

```
self.ttitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(74,16,190,16)];
self.ttitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[self.ttitle setText: [NSString  stringWithFormat: @"yourtext"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.ttitle];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This question is not about customizing UILabel. If you have a UIView and add a sub view of UILabel, you can change the position or size of this label any time programmatically. The same don’t hold true when the label is in a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use the create uitableviewcell and it's controller outlet to the appropriate controls on it and use it like custom tableview.