# UIButton titleLabel frame size returning CGSize with zero width & height

Tags: ios, ios8

For iOS7, I used the `UIButton` `titleLabel.frame.size.width` property to determine the width of my button title under different localisations so I could position the title correctly using `contentInset` on the `UIButton`.

My `UIButton` is setup with an image and title and I always want the combination of these two to be centred horizontally in the `UIButton` for example:

```
[space-x (image) space-y (titleLabel) space-x]
```

Under iOS 7 and Xcode 5.1, the following code works perfectly (even running on iOS 8 GM when built in XCode 5.1):

```
CGSize buttonSize = button.frame.size;
CGSize titleSize = button.titleLabel.frame.size;
float contentInset =((buttonSize.width - (titleSize.width + 18 + 3)) / 2 );
float contentInsetRounded = roundf(contentInset);
[button setContentEdgeInsets:(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, contentInsetRounded, 0, 0))];
```

*(18 is the width of the image, and 3 is the number of points spacing between the image and `titleLabel` or space-y in my example above)*

Under iOS 8 and Xcode 6 GM, `button.titleLabel.frame.size` is returning a `CGSize` with zero width & height so my contentInset ends up centring the `UIImage` in the `UIButton`, causing the `titleLabel` to truncate.

Any ideas? I tried setting the `titleLabel` text immediately before this code in case it thought it was empty but that didn't help either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW, `button.titleLabel.frame.size` is of type `CGSize`, which is a struct. By `nil`, you must be meaning a `CGSize` with width and height both 0.0.

Comment: Can you answer your own question and let us know how you solved the issue or where you made a mistake?

Comment: Sorry I mean I've fixed the question to refer to CGSize rather than nil value. Still no solution unfortunately.

Comment: On what event do call that code (like `viewDidLoad`)?

Comment: @mostruash Yes its called on `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Try doing it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Views are not added to the view hierarchy yet in `viewDidLoad`. You should do the same thing for both iOS7 & iOS8.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60945/discussion-between-staticnz-and-mostruash).

Comment: try in viewDidAppear method, it worked for me

Answer (score 18):

Set the title text, then make a sizeToFit for the title label, and try to get the titleLabel.frame.size.width

```
[myButton setTitle:@"My Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton.titleLabel sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 15):

I **resolved** it. App run on iOS8, build by Xcode 6, not update frame right after UIButton `setTitle`, `setTitleEdgeInsets`. It will wait for next UI update. So, if you get frame of titleLabel, you will get CGRectZero.

**Solution**:

1. Call below methods after set UI property, to update layout immediately:

   [self setNeedsLayout];
   [self layoutIfNeeded];

Or:

2. Delay a second, and you can get `titleFrame`, use `self.titleLabel.frame`.

Or:

3. dispatch_async in main queue, to move code to next queue

Comment: that's saved my life :)

Comment: For more info on setNeedsLayout/layoutIfNeeded combo see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2931712/1014048

Comment: What does "set UI property" means?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Somethings like [button setContentEdgeInsets...]

Answer (score 2):

If you are then setting an image next to a button after getting the frame, you can use

```
[theButton setTitle: @"theTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[theButton setImage: theImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[theButton setNeedsLayout];
[theButton layoutIfNeeded];
[theButton setImageEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, transactionsButton.titleLabel.frame.size.width + 40.0, 0, 0)];
```

And in Swift 3, this will do.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will not work for you, but I had the same problem when running my code in XCode 6 GM / iOS8 and could not get it to work. It worked randomly and I ended up using a different approach instead of an NSString I used an NSAttributedString as the title.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Button text"];
NSTextAttachment* textAttachment = [NSTextAttachment new];
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Arrows"];
NSAttributedString *finalString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
[attributedText appendAttributedString:finalString];
```

Only caveat is that it’s iOS7 and up, but seems to work flawless.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had greatly over engineered myself into this problem. I took out all of my content inset code and therefore didn't need to find the frame.size. I now just centre the button titles and all is well!

Still seems there is an issue with getting the frame.size but for my needs, I can work around it.

Answer (score 0):

So we can try this code :

```
func withTitleAndImageAlign(title:String,image:UIImage,RL_Space:CGFloat) {
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        let buttonWidth = frame.size.width
        let textWidth = titleLabel?.frame.size.width
        let imageWidth = imageView?.frame.size.width
        let lim = buttonWidth  - (textWidth! + imageWidth! + (2 * RL_Space) )
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: lim)
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: lim, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
```