# How can I finished one view's constrains before other view generate

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

Now, I am going to generate a titleview that its height is variable for the tableHeaderView.so i need to confirm the titleview's hegiht before the tableview generate

```
//titleView
JMProductTitleView *titleView = [[JMProductTitleView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, JMDeviceWidth, 300)];
titleView.delegate = self;
JMProductDetailModel *model = [JMPorductDetailTool createProductDetailModel];
titleView.model = model;
_titleView = titleView;

//
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, JMDeviceWidth, JMDeviceHeight) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.tableHeaderView = titleView;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
_tableView = tableView;
```

Comment: You can try using [self.view layoutIfNeeded]. It will force the view to layout all the constraints.

Comment: Amazing! it works for me .Thanks a lot.I had used [self.view setNeedsLayout],but it didn't work.I don't know why.Could you tell me the difference between them?

Comment: Well i'm not sure myself except that all i know is, layoutIfNeeded internally calls all the functions that force the UI to get setup.

Go to this page, itll probably clear some stuff up

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807137/what-is-the-relationship-between-uiviews-setneedslayout-layoutifneeded-and-lay

Also i'll add it as an answer as it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [self.view layoutIfNeeded]. It will force the view to layout all the constraints.