# iOS UIView : setNeedLayout, setNeedDisplay, layoutSubViews and layoutIfNeeded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Can anyone tell that 
what these 4 methods definition and what they do

```
 1. setNeedLayout
 2. setNeedDisplay
 3. layoutSubViews
 4. layoutIfNeeded.
```

I googled a lot can't find a good answer.

Comment: as I remember calling just `setNeedsLayout ` will ensure calling `layoutIfNeeded ` and `layoutSubViews ` also

Comment: Please add as answer it will help other too :)

Comment: In the right hand got similar answer, probably you havent searched correctly? like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609206/setneedslayout-vs-setneedsupdateconstraints-and-layoutifneeded-vs-updateconstra) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807137/what-is-the-relationship-between-uiviews-setneedslayout-layoutifneeded-and-lay?rq=1), their answer have details

Comment: i go through both links already i need a simple explanations

Comment: Why don't you just command+click on those methods and see inside. :) @AbhishekThapliyal

Comment: Usually you only need to call `layoutIfNeeded` if you make changes to constraint to make the view update it, also can put it in `UIView.animated` to animate the whole layout update

Comment: @iPeter : Thanks for this idea :)

Comment: check this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2931712/4831524

Answer (score 4):

1. `setNeedsLayout` is useful for calling the 4th one `layoutIfNeeded`. It makes it really needed.
2. `setNeedsDisplay` makes `drawRect` method called at the next run loop iteration and is not really related to the rest of three methods in question
3. `layoutSubviews` performs actual layout of the view's subviews
4. `layoutIfNeeded` calls `layoutSubviews` when it is needed. You can make it needed by using the 1st method `setNeedsLayout`

Comment: Thanks for Answering. It will great help if explain more on these. :)

Comment: What exactly you want to be explained?

Comment: The other answer have detail explained, you said you want simple explaination, i think he does well